# PlaceAutoCompleteFragment closing issue

Tags: android, kotlin, placeautocompletefragment

I facing sudden closing of PlaceAutocompleteFragment. 
I am getting this error `Status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null}`

My xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kiranbj.androidtcps.Main3Activity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MyKotlin code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3)
        val autocompleteFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment) as PlaceAutocompleteFragment
        val typeFilter = AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
                .build()
        autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter)
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this)
    }
```

Manifest

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"  />
```

added keys in google_map_key file

Comment: have you add api key in meta-data tag in manifest

Comment: Yes.....I added

Comment: may be your app exceeds the limit for request place api https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage .  Try to change the  google_maps_key

Comment: It is a fresh api key

Comment: Have you enable `Google Place API` from  API Console

Comment: @KapilRajput thanks a lot it solved my problem